# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.parse

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am trying to create a namged range in excel file using apache poi using below code.

```
 private static void createNamedRangesForGeneratedValues(final XSSFWorkbook workBook,                   final String name, final String cellAreaRange) {
        final Name cellRangeName = workBook.createName();
        cellRangeName.setNameName(name);

        final String reference = name + cellAreaRange; // "!A1:C5"; // area reference
        cellRangeName.setRefersToFormula(reference);
```

But at this step :  `cellRangeName.setRefersToFormula(reference);` throwing following exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.parse(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/apache/poi/ss/formula/FormulaParsingWorkbook;II)[Lorg/apache/poi/hssf/record/formula/Ptg;
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFName.setRefersToFormula(XSSFName.java:195)
    at test.java.ExcelSheetDropDownDataHandler.createNamedRangesForGeneratedValues(ExcelSheetDropDownDataHandler.java:186)
    at test.java.ExcelSheetDropDownDataHandler.generateCountryData(ExcelSheetDropDownDataHandler.java:93)
    at test.java.ExcelSheetDropDownDataHandler.generateData(ExcelSheetDropDownDataHandler.java:64)
    at test.java.ExcelSheetDropDownDataHandler.createDataTab(ExcelSheetDropDownDataHandler.java:50)
    at test.java.ExcelSheetDropDownDataHandler.main(ExcelSheetDropDownDataHandler.java:205)
```

Could anybody please suggest, what could be the reason for this?

Comment: sounds like outdated binaries, which jars are you using (names and versions)?

Comment: Hi, plz find jar versions. POI 3.9, poi-ooxml-3.5, xmlbeans.jar -2.6

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You appear to have mis-matched jars. From your comment you say you have `POI 3.9 .... poi-ooxml-3.5`. You **must** have matching jars, so POI-3.9 and POI-OOXML-3.9. You can't mix and match new and old jars from different parts of the project.

If you need help with working out where your jars are coming from (eg your app framework is bundling old ones), see [this POI FAQ entry](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10006). To check what the dependencies are of the different parts of Apache POI, see the [Components page](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components)

You'll either want to update all of your POI jars to 3.9 final, or all of them to 3.10 beta 1 (the latest version as of July 2013)